# PHP - how to access right path to file?

Tags: php, url, path, filepath, file-exists

```
$filename='../uploadedimages/project-'.$item->id.'-'.$imgId;
$filename=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploadedimages/project-'.$item->id.'-'.$imgId;
```

I was trying to use both first and second way to find path to file and verify if file exists by 
`file_exists()`. First one doesn't work because `file_exists()` doesn't accept relative path and second is returning wrong, non-existing path: `http://www.kvetena.local/data/www/kvetena.local/web/uploadedimages/project-4-0`

Right path is: `Z:\kvetena.local\web\uploadedimages\` but it will be changed in future. How could I access files in that folder?

Answer (score 0):

Use [realpath](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) to get an absolute path:

```
$absPath = realpath($filenamed);
```

Comment: $filename='../uploadedimages/project-'.$item->id.'-'.$imgId;
echo "<img src='".realpath($filename)."' ></img>"; this doesnt work - returning empty "" path

Comment: It may return empty string, because `realpath` returned `false`. Read manual section about this case: it may happend because the files doesn't exist or the user, you're running the script from, has no rights.

Answer (score 0):

If you will use only images I can suggest you another way to check if file exist

```
function file_exists_url($url){
        if(@GetImageSize($url)) return true;
        else return false;
    }
```

You can use this function with relative pathes

Comment: it doesnt work, returning false with '../uploadedimages/project-'.$item->id.'-'.$imgId; path, even if file exists